# mod_wsgi download in virtualenv

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I am trying to configure mod_wsgi in a virtualenv that has Django installed. When I run the `./configure` command, I get the following, which looks ok:

```
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
checking Apache version... 2.2.22
checking for python... /Users/talaniz/tmp/newproject/DJANGO/bin/python
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

but when I try to run `make`, I get the error: `-bash: make: command not found`

Question: I see the next step of this is `sudo make install`, do I need to configure it outside of the virtualenv in order to get this to work?

Comment: You don't have the 'make' command installed, nothing to do with Python.

Comment: Thank you! I am on Xcode right now downloading the command line tools!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can install mod_wsgi into a virtual environment. You can however tell mod_wsgi to use a particular virtual environment for each site.

Comment: Thanks, Enrico. I was just looking at the documentation. It looks like the virtualenv's sit on top of the mod_wsgi layer and refer to depending on how it's configured: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments